# GSAP and IntersectionObserver: Text .from opacity:0 to 1 flashing before animation

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap, intersection-observer

I am using GSAP and IntersectionObserver to animate every character of every `h1` on scroll.

Everything seems to be working but the `opacity` part of the animation doesn't work as expected. Basically one can see the `h1` before it goes to `opacity:0` and then back to 1 (it reminds me of the infamous Flash Of Unstyled Text).
I am using the `.from` method. I would like every `h1` to be invisible before the animation but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
Please check the snippet.

```js
const titles = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
    const options = {
      root: null,
      threshold: 0.25,
      rootMargin: "-200px"
    };
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
          return;
        }
        entry.target.classList.add("anim-text");
        // TEXT SPLITTING
        const animTexts = document.querySelectorAll(".anim-text");
    
        animTexts.forEach(text => {
          const strText = text.textContent;
          const splitText = strText.split("");
          text.textContent = "";
    
          splitText.forEach(item => {
            text.innerHTML += "<span>" + item + "</span>";
          });
        });
        // END TEXT SPLITTING
    
        // TITLE ANIMATION
        const charTl = gsap.timeline();
    
        charTl.set("h1", { opacity: 1 }).from(
          ".anim-text span",
          {
            opacity: 0,
            x: 40,
            stagger: {
              amount: 1
            }
          },
          "+=0.5"
        );
        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        // END TITLE ANIMATION
      });
    }, options);
    
    titles.forEach(title => {
      observer.observe(title);
    });
```

```css
* {
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #279AF1;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

section {
  padding: 2em;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sec-1 {
  background-color: #EA526F;
}

.sec-2 {
  background-color: #23B5D3;
}

.sec-3 {
  background-color: #F9C80E;
}

.sec-4 {
  background-color: #662E9B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">Scroll Down</div>
<section class="sec-1">
  <h1>FIRST</h1>
</section>
<section class="sec-2">
  <h1>SECOND</h1>
</section>
<section class="sec-3">
  <h1>THIRD</h1>
</section>
<section class="sec-4">
  <h1>FOURTH</h1>
</section>
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a flash of unstyled content (FOUC) that occurs because the JavaScript waits to run until the page has loaded. GreenSock actually has [a tutorial on removing FOUC](https://greensock.com/fouc/) that I recommend.

The basic approach is to hide the elements using your CSS and modify your JS to work with the changed CSS (such as changing the .from() to a .to() or .fromTo()). You could do that by adding `h1 { opacity: 0 }` to your CSS and then add the following to the JS: `gsap.set(h1, {opacity: 1});`.

Side note: GSAP has its own [SplitText plugin](http://greensock.com/splittext) that makes it easy to customize how the text is split (including by line), handles non-standard characters, and adds the ability to easily revert to the default. I highly recommend it if you're going to be splitting text up!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the problem persists. I think the problem should be the fact that I am animating the span (=each character) while the whole `h1` remains untouched and therefore visible. But the `h1` needs to be visible before the span starts animating, right? I don't see the point adding an opacity animation on the whole `h1` in the same timeline. I guess I could hard-code every character of every `h1` in a span, but it seems very cumbersome to me.

Comment: @Vito Ah, sorry. I didn't look at your code carefully (this is why providing minimal demos is useful). The core approach is the same, just hide what you need to be hidden. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just one little correction, which made the whole thing working as I wanted: on the `.set` method I changed the selector to `entry.target` in order to get each `h1` that has beed scrolled to. I didn't know I could do this kind of selection. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thought I did ^__^